# Auto mapping one to one foreign keys in asp.net boilerplate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, automapper, asp.net-boilerplate

Suppose I have the following class structure:

```
public class Pizza
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PizzaType PizzaType { get; set; }
}

public class PizzaType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need a DTO class so I can pass to the UI an object for edit, and then pass back to the service for saving to the database. Thus:

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Pizza))]
public class PizzaEdit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PizzaTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to map between `Pizza` and `PizzaEdit` as easily as possible so it can be edited in the UI and saved back to the database. Preferably, this will "just work".

What do I need to do to get a mapping from `Pizza` to `PizzaEdit` to work and include `PizzaTypeId` in the DTO object?

`pizzaObj.MapTo<PizzaEdit>()` works but `PizzaTypeId` is always null.

I'm open to changing the class structure as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add property `PizzaTypeId` to `Pizza` class, it will become `FK` to `PizzaType` table.

```
public class Pizza
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PizzaType PizzaType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PizzaType")]
    public int PizzaTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

or without `FK`(*NotMapped*) via `LazyLoading`:

```
public class Pizza
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PizzaType PizzaType { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int PizzaTypeId { get { return PizzaType.Id; } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this but in my actual model PizzaTypeId was a `long` and I was trying to map it to an `int`, which would cause it to fail.